# Compilation errors for oracle SQL - stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

```
create table employee
( 
employedID number,
employeeName varchar2(30),
deptid number,
salary number
);

Create table department
(
deptid number,
deptname varchar2(30)
);

 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertemp
(
PemployedID IN number,
PemployeeName IN varchar,
Pdepid IN number,
Psalary IN number
)

IS
BEGIN

IF Pdepid NOT IN (SELECT * from department.deptid) THEN

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (PemployedID,’PemployeeName’,00,Psalary);

ELSE
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (PemployedID,’PemployeeName’,Pdepid, Psalary);

END IF;

COMMIT;
END;
/
```

I am trying to create a stored procedure and I am not that familiar with oracle SQl syntax. If Pdepid is not there in  table department then I would like to insert a record in table employees with 00 as the Pdepid. For this I am using IF statements. I am getting compilation errors for this procedure.

Comment: And what is the error? (hint: run `show errors` to see it)

Comment: It says that Sub Query is not possible in this line:-

Comment: IF Pdepid NOT IN (SELECT * from department.deptid) THEN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that should work in Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertemp
(
PemployedID IN number,
PemployeeName IN varchar,
Pdepid IN number,
Psalary IN number
)

IS

v_tmp NUMBER;
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(1) INTO v_tmp
FROM department
WHERE deptid = Pdepid;

IF v_tmp = 0 THEN

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (PemployedID,PemployeeName,00,Psalary);

ELSE
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (PemployedID,PemployeeName,Pdepid, Psalary);

END IF;


END;
```

---

And you can simplify this function like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertemp
(
PemployedID IN number,
PemployeeName IN varchar,
Pdepid IN number,
Psalary IN number
)

IS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (PemployedID,PemployeeName,
DECODE((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM department WHERE deptid = Pdepid), 0, 0, Pdepid),Psalary);

END;
```

Comment: thats really smart, let me try that out